# Unable to apply menu flyout to listview

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, expression-blend

I am unable to apply a menu flyout to a listview.
I assume my app crashes once the my app attempts to load the specified XAML.

My code is below:

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.Contacts}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name">          
    <ListViewItem>
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
                <behaviors:MoveContactBehavior />
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Family" 
                                    Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Friend" 
                                    Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Business" 
                                    Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Behavior:

```
public class MoveContactBehavior : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        var senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

        flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You "assume"? Do you hit any exceptions, errors in debug window, anything that would help?

Comment: It goes straight to unhandled exceptions handler. I have configured my solution to break on exception from all sources. I receive a Catastrophic Error message as the exception message.

Comment: Can you remove CommandParameter from all MenuFlyoutItems to see what happens?

Comment: No effect. Still crashes. This works on a hyperlink button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

I removed DisplayMemberPath from the ListView and added a DataTemplate.
Everything works now.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}">
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
        <behaviors:MoveContactAction />
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Family" Command="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Friend" Command="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Business" Command="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Others" Command="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
    </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

This was implemented with this [app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc).